# how to use dip and sip in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

hello and hi everyone, 
can anyone suggest me how to use device independent pixels(dip),sip and convert px to dip with a sample code..

Comment: You should start to accept some of your answers otherwise you'll have hard times getting new ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this out.

> **Density-independent pixel (dip)**
>
> A virtual pixel unit that applications can use in defining their UI, to express layout dimensions or position in a density-independent way.
> The density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a 160 dpi screen, the baseline density assumed by the platform (as described later in this document). At run time, the platform transparently handles any scaling of the dip units needed, based on the actual density of the screen in use. The conversion of dip units to screen pixels is simple: **pixels = dips * (density / 160)**. For example, on 240 dpi screen, 1 dip would equal 1.5 physical pixels. Using dip units to define your application's UI is highly recommended, as a way of ensuring proper display of your UI on different screens.

Comment: And to specify it you simply type, for example, `android:layout_marginRight="5dp"` or `android:textSize="22sp"`